# Dataframe drop rows base on row hash value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
dic = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }
df.drop(df[dic[df.id] == 'a'].index)
```

I want to drop rows that have `dic[df.id] == 'a'`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

which is expected since `df.id` is a Series rather than the row value.
What is the right way to go about extracting the row value of `df.id` for filtering through a dictionary?

Comment: `dic[df.id]` is attempting to use the **entire** `Series`, `df['id']`, as a key to your dictionary. The error is telling you that it's impossible because dict keys need to be hashable (which a Series is not), but this isn't what you're looking to do in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `map`

```
dic = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }
out_df = df.drop(df[df.id.map(dic) == 'a'].index)
```